# Preventing a non-root user from running a shell script

Tags: bash

Hi I made a script as root called `whatever` and saved it in `/`

I then made a new user `adduser guest`

when i log in as guest via `su - guest` and try to run the script with `cd / && ./whatever`

I get `permission denied` which is good, but all i have to do is `bash /whatever` and it works.

<strike>Is the correct sollution to chmod `/bin/bash`?</strike>  **No**

Comment: Im just revisiting this question from google and am shocked the stack exchange nazi's downvoted it :(, its helping me again :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow a user to run a shell script, you have to give them both "execute" and "read" permissions on the file.

If you want to prevent a user from running a shell script, you have to remove the "read" permission. Even if the file is marked as executable, the user can not execute a non-readable script.

There is no way to allow a user to execute but not read a shell script.

Similarly, there is no way to allow a user to read but not to execute a shell script.

Comment: `there is no way to allow a user to read but not to execute a shell script.`

+100

Thanks, I cannot believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

No!

Never touch the permissions on anything in `/bin`. You need to change the permissions on `./whatever`. You'll need to add execute permissions to it - `chmod u+x ./whatever`. If you want it to run.

If however, you want to *stop* someone running it... well, you have to set it unreadable. Because there's no difference between a script you can read and a script you can 'run'. They're just sequences of commands.

Comment: The problem is that doesnt work.

I can still do `cd / && bash ./whatever` from the `guest` account.

from `root` I can do both `./whatever` and `bash ./whatever`

Comment: Who owns 'whatever'? Try `a+x` - it's definitely the execute permission on the script that's missing.

Comment: `root` owns `whatever`

no matter what I do `bash ./whatever` runs the script. modifying permissions is only affecting execution via `./whatever`

The problem was I needed to do `-r` for random users.